# How to sort and delete old directories based on the folder name which is in date

Tags: batch-file

So I have a folder called Folder1 and inside of that folder has multiple other Folders for our build. The naming convention of those build folders are the date that they were built. For example: `20190314141438` (which is 2019-03-14 time 14:14:38). So what I like to do is to delete everything except for the last latest 3 folders. I started it out in a batch script but was able to delete it based on last modified date, which works, but need to somehow compare all the folders name and delete the old ones. Here is my script:

```
if not exist "%Location%" (
    echo The Location - "%Location%" does not exist
) ELSE (
    for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in ('dir "%Location%" /AD /B /O-D 2^>nul') do (
        echo Removing "%Location%\%%i"
        rd /Q /S "%Location%\%%i"
    )
)
```

I was also thinking if it's not possible with a batch script, I can create a java program that does that if anyone has any idea on how i should start. Thanks.

UPDATE: 
Some of the folders will also have a release number at the end of the folder name such as 20190314141438_Release2. How would I tell the batch file to ignore those. I was thinking of using `findstr /C:"Release1"`and somehow put that in a if else statement?

Comment: Since the folder names are equal length I'd order by name descending `/O-N` not by LastWriteTime/LastModified.

Comment: You mean the time is `14:38` in your example, don't you?

Comment: @LotPings I'm going to try /O-N, but what if they are not all equal, their might be some with time that is exactly lets say 14:14 without any seconds

Comment: @aschipfl the timing is 14:14:38 which is 2:14 and 38 seconds

Comment: Ordering by name implies a string comparison, char by char starting from 1st. So missing seconds don't matter. BTW to have `2019-03-14 time 14:14:38` is had to be `20190314141438`

Comment: @LotPings Oh, didn't realize I have entered the name incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: Also I found out that the some of the folders will have release numbers at the end of them, for example 20190314141438_Release1,. I don't want to delete any of those. I'll update my question

Comment: Try `for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in ('dir "%Location%" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /C:Release') do` to filter output of __DIR__ with __FINDSTR__ which outputs just all lines __NOT__ containing the string `Release`.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks, it worked! It's much simpler than what I was going to do

Answer (score 0):

Thank you LotPings and Mofi for helping me out with this question. I have posted the script that works:

```
if not exist "%Location%" (
    echo The Location - "%Location%" does not exist
) ELSE (
    for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%i in ('dir "%Location%" /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul ^| 
             %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /C:Release') do
        echo Removing "%Location%\%%i"
        rd /Q /S "%Location%\%%i"
    )
)
```